# ¿Cómo pasar datos de una tabla a otra mediante un modulo de traslados en Django?

Tags: django, ajax, select2

Actualmente uso Django 1.9 con Postgresql.

En mi módulo de traslados ocupo seleccionar un rancho en un select y, en div abajo, mostrar los animales pertenecientes al mismo en el lado izquierdo. Del lado derecho, seleccionar el rancho al que se quieren migrar y un botón de acción para mover los registros.

Mis dudas serían las siguientes:

1. Cómo poder mover los registros de una tabla a otra.
2. Qué me convendría usar para pintar los registros de los animales (he intentado con una tabla, multiselect con checkboxes y dropdown pero se me complica con todas..).

**Views**
class TrasladarView(View):

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = {"success": True}
    try:
        rancho = Rancho.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('id', 0))

        animales=[]
        # filtrar animales vivos de los ranchos
        for animal in rancho.animal_set.filter(status=Animal.VIVO):
            animales.append({
                "id": animal.id,
                "nombre": animal.nombre
            })
        data['animales'] = animales

    except Rancho.DoesNotExist:
        data["success"] =False
        data["message"] = "No se encontro el rancho"
    except Exception, e:
        data["success"] = False
        data["message"] = e.message
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**Traslados.html**

```
<div class="x_panel">
  <div class="x_title">
    <h2>Procedencia</h2>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="x_content">
    <br/><br>
      <div class="form-group">
          <select name="select_origen" class="form-control" id="select_origen">
              <option value="rancho_origen" selected >Rancho de origen..</option>
              {% for nombres in ranchos %}
                    <option value="{{ nombres.id }}">{{ nombres.nombre_rancho }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
          </select>
      </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="x_content multipleSelect" id="div_origen" style= "display:none;">

                  <!-- start -->
                  <select id='sOrigen' multiple='multiple'>
                    {% for nombres in animales %}
                    <option value='{{ nombres.id }}'>{{ nombres.nombre }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                  <!-- ends -->
              </div>
              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
              <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                <a onclick="limpiar()" class="btn btn-app" id="limpiar"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>Limpiar</a>
                <a onclick="selectAll()" class="btn btn-app" id="limpiar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Seleccionar todo</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-app" id="mover"><i class="fa fa-send"></i>Mover</a>
          </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**ajax que imprime en consola los ids por de los animales del rancho 
seleccionado en el "select"**

> ```
>        function dataSelect(){
>                 var id_s_origen=$('#select_origen').val();
>                 if(id_s_origen=='rancho_origen'){
>                   ignora el option estático del select_origen al ser seleccionado y no lo manda al server#}
>                     return;
>                 }
>                 $.ajax({
>                     url: '{% url "animales:trasladar" %}',
>                     data: {
>                         id:id_s_origen
>                     },
>                     dataType:'json',
>                     method:'GET',
>                     success: function(data){
>                         if(data.success){
>                             $.each(data.animales,function(index,item){
>                                 console.log(item)
>                             })
>                         }else{
>                             alert(data.message)
>                         }
>                         console.log(data)
>                     },
>                     error: function(error){
>                         console.log('error!')
>                     },
>                 })
>         }
> ```

[image: Lista de ids de animales por consola después de seleccionar un rancho]

Comment: Hola @IsaAlejandro. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Al incluir código es preferible que pegues el texto, y no la imagen. Por otro lado, ¿podrías aclarar si estás intentando sólo modificar el HTML, en qué momento guardarías en la base de datos? Además, ¿podrías [edit] la pregunta mostrando lo que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Hola @Mariano, muchas gracias, si, soy nuevo en este asunto haha !!

Comment: pues lo que quiero es modificar los registros de una tabla moviendolos a otra, y que soolo se refleje en los divs que se muestran en el template.

En lo que ando perdido precisamente igual es la momento de hacer la consulta para poder mover los registros y mandarlos a la otra tabla en la base, hasta ahora solo he quitado uno de los divs y en el que ha quedado inserté un plugin que por el momento me muestra todos los animales de todos los ranchos, cosa que corregiré porque solo se ocupan los animales del rancho seleccionado

Comment: Son varias preguntas a la vez, algunas relacionadas con Django otras con el frontend. Limita tu publicación a una sola pregunta y crea las publicaciones que necesites para las preguntas restantes. Intenta crear un __[mcve]__ para cada pregunta.